# Insert multiple data into a single cell SQLyog vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sqlyog

I am trying to develop a management system for dentists, this the system i am developing

[THIS MY PROGRAM'S SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrvy9.png)
when the dentist inputted a data on a textbox, it will be saved on the database and whenever the dentist insert a data again on that textbox, instead of replacing the older data with a newer data, it will store the data, making the cell store multiple data

and this is my code for adding data into the table

table name: teethhistory

database name: PatientManagementSystem

```
Private Sub txtURThirdMolar_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtURThirdMolar.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
           MySqlConn.Open()
           query1 = "SELECT * FROM teethhistory WHERE Patient_ID_Number ='" & lblID.Text & "'"
            cmd1 = New MySqlCommand(query1, MySqlConn)
            reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader

            If reader.HasRows Then
                Dim i As Integer
                With cmd
                    .Connection = MySqlConn
                    .CommandText = "UPDATE teethhistory SET Up_Right_3rd_Molar ='" & txtURThirdMolar.Text & "' WHERE Patient_ID_Number = " & lblID.Text
                    reader.Close()
                    i = .ExecuteNonQuery
                End With

            If i > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Updated!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
            Else
                MsgBox("Failed", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Failed")
            End If

        Else
           Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = MySqlConn.CreateCommand
                cmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO teethhistory (Patient_ID_Number, Fullname, Up_Right_3rd_Molar )" &
                                            "VALUES ('{0}' ,'{1}' ,'{2}')",
                                            lblID.Text,
                                            lblFullname.Text,
                                            txtURThirdMolar.Text)
                reader.close()
                Dim affectedrows As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                If affectedrows > 0 Then
                    MsgBox("Saved!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
                Else
                    MsgBox("Saving failed.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Failed")

                End If
                MySqlConn.close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: and what is your problem??

Comment: my problem is, when i insert data on that textbox and saved it on the database, it only replace the old data with the new one. What i want to do is to able to insert multiple data into a single cell

Comment: If you want it to INSERT every time, why is that UPDATE query even there?

Comment: Also; parametise your queries to avoid the risk of SQL injection.

Comment: because if i do not put an update query, it will duplicate a patient, in order to avoid duplication of data, i use that update query

Answer (score 0):

if you want to Append the Existing text In field with new data from textbox,use Update command as

```
 .CommandText = "UPDATE teethhistory SET Up_Right_3rd_Molar = concat('" & txtURThirdMolar.Text & "',Up_Right_3rd_Molar)   WHERE Patient_ID_Number = " & lblID.Text
```

for inserting values seperated by commas, just insert a comma before the string ion `concat` function.

hope i undestood your problem well and this solves it.

Comment: Thanks bro, gonna try this :)

Comment: there's an error, it says "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value"

Comment: i have another question, how about separate it with comma? for example i inserted "a" then "b" and in the database, it will be like this "a, b"